# How to insert location on ACF google map field from frontend form?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having a custom form having an address field and I want to put the address value to the ACF google map field

I have used the `update_field('field_5c87a29f0ad9a' , $address , $post_id);`
but it is not working.

Comment: I have a custom form in frontend. I have an address named field where users can put their location. Now I have an advanced custom field of google map in the dashboard. I want to insert that value to the acf google map field.

Comment: I have tried  update_field('field_5c87a29f0ad9a' , $address , $post_id);  this code for the value to update but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```php
$coordinates = getCoordinates($fullAddress);

$coordinates = explode(",", $coordinates);

$latitude = $coordinates[0];
$longitude = $coordinates[1];

$google_map_mark = array();
array_push($google_map_mark, "address");
array_push($google_map_mark, $fullAddress);
array_push($google_map_mark, "lat");
array_push($google_map_mark, $latitude);
array_push($google_map_mark, "lng");
array_push($google_map_mark, $longitude);

$value = array("address" => $fullAddress, "lat" => $latitude, "lng" => $longitude);

update_post_meta($post_id, 'coordinates', $value);
```